# Is it possible to debug JS loaded via loadScript when running under Lightning Web Security?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-web-security

I'm trying to use a third-party JS tool ([Fancybox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/api/options/) in this case, but the specific tool isn't important) via `loadScript` in an LWC.  I can see that it loads (the promise completes without error), but it isn't working correctly.  However, all of my attempts to debug the issue have failed.  If I add console logging to the script, I can see it, but the source link in the JS Console is always `aura_proddebug.js`, not the loaded JS.  I also cannot find the loaded JS in the JS Console's Debugger panel either.

I am actually working in an public (not logged in) Experience Builder page, but I [enabled Debug Mode for the Site Guest user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343055/enable-lightning-components-debug-mode-for-a-guest-user).  I'm still unable to debug anything loaded via `loadScript`.  The best I've been able to do is wrap a try-catch around things to see any exceptions being generated, which is better than nothing, but doesn't solve all of my issues.